# Can't place an icon at a known coordinate at a map

Tags: c#, uwp, maps, esri

I have these constants:

```
private const double DOWN_LEFTX = 31.327089;
private const double DOWN_LEFTY = 34.848469;
```

and I would like to place a symbol at those exact coordinates.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Initialize_map();
}

private void Initialize_map()
{
    // Create a map with 'Imagery with Labels' basemap and an initial location
    Map myMap = new Map(BasemapType.ImageryWithLabels, 32.560407, 35.608784, 16);
    MyMapView.Map = myMap;                   
    // Set the map views graphics overlay to the created graphics overlay.
    MyMapView.GraphicsOverlays.Add(theGraphicsOverlays);
    theGraphicCollection.Add(new Graphic(new MapPoint(DOWN_LEFTX, DOWN_LEFTY), new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbolStyle.X, System.Drawing.Color.Red, 14)));
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work. My initial thought was that the object `MapPoint` is using different coordinate format, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the problem, like is it almost working ? or not at all ?

Comment: its not working at all.

Comment: Have youtried to put the icon at the same coodinates a the map ? Also have you tried to zoom out ?

Comment: Yes I zoomed all the way out and changed coordinates and it still didn't work

Comment: Have you seen this example ? https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/api-reference/html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Symbology_SimpleMarkerSymbol.htm There seem to be a parameter SpatialReference when creating the mapPoint. And maybe try to use the same mapPoint object to create the map and the graphic